# Qt: QGraphicsLineItem position in QGraphicsScene

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsscene

I have a problem with determining position of `QGraphicsLineItem`.  I want to move items on the scene relatively, so I need to know their position. I have few `QGraphicsPixmapItem` objects and I do not have problem with them because `pixmapItem.pos()` gives me realistic position of every item in scene coordinates. But with  `QGraphicsLineItem`s i get the same coordinate (0,0) for every line. Here is code:

```
QGraphicsLineItem*line = new QGraphicsLineItem();
scene->addItem(line);
line->setLine(QLineF(0,VVR-i*(OH),HVR,VVR-i*(OH)));
```

This code draws lines in correct position, but its coordinates are set to `(0,0)` not to `(0,VVR-i*(OH))`.

The following code should move the line item by (VVR + OH) when it reaches position greater than VVR. But since all lines have starting position (0,0), wherever I put them, all lines are moved at the same time.

```
QPointF current_pos = line->pos();
if (current_pos.y() >= VVR)
{
    line->setPos(current_pos.x(),current_pos.y()-(VVR+(OH)));
}
```

How can I get the real (scene) coordinates of the `QGraphicsLineItem`, as I get for `QGraphicsPixmapItem` Thanks!

Comment: To get the position of the line in the scene, use the function scenePos(), instead of pos(), which will return the object's position in scene coordinates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each graphics item has initial position at `(0, 0)`. You can set its new position using `setPos`. All its contents will be shifted according to new position.

But `setLine` doesn't change item position. This method change the object the item represents instead. For example, an object can be `(0, 5) - (5, 5)` line. If you didn't set item position, the position remains at `(0, 0)` and the line is shown at `(0, 5) - (5, 5)`. If you set e.g. position `(2, 0)`, the line will be shifted to `(2, 5) - (7, 5)` position. There are methods similar to `setLine` in other basic graphics item classes (e.g. `QGraphicsPixmapItem::setOffset`).

If you want to get the line position that was set previously by `setLine()`, use `line()` method. If you shifted the item using `setPos()`, use `pos()`.

Additionally, since you said that you want to move items on the scene relatively, I'd like to mention the following fact. If you set a parent item for an item, its position will be calculated relatively to the parent item. You might find it useful.

Answer (score 3):

Although it's a bit strange to ask for the "line of the lineitem", I believe you want:

> QPointF current_pos = line->line().p1();